Simple Expression of Sine/Cosine Functions at Half Multiples of $\pi$?
It can be easily noticed that for multiples of $\pi$, the value of the trigonometric functions Sine and Cosine simplify to a simple expression:



$n$
$\sin(n \pi)$
$\cos(n \pi)$




0
0
+1


1
0
-1


2
0
+1


3
0
-1


4
0
+1


$n$
0
$(-1)^n$



Is it possible to represent the values of Sine/Cosine Functions at Half Multiples of $\pi$ in a similar fashion?



$n$
$\sin \left( \frac{n}{2} \pi \right)$
$\cos \left( \frac{n}{2} \pi \right)$




0
0
+1


1
+1
0


2
0
-1


3
-1
0


4
0
+1


$n$
?
?




Imaginary and real parts of $i^n$?

Any restrictions you would want to enforce on the nature of such a formula? E.g. would a pedestrian approach like $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}n\right) = (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\left(n-2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right)$ fit your needs?

There are times when a repeating sequence such as $0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1$ occurs outside of trigonometry, in which case a convenient formula for it is $\sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right)$. But it's also usually possible to just omit the zero terms in those cases, so you end up with $1,-1,1,-1$.

Note that $f(n)=n(n+1)/2$ is a sequence of integers that goes odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, ...
In particular, this means $g(n)=(-1)^{f(n)}$ is the sequence
$$-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, \ldots$$
Now, shift this left by 1 step to find $g(n+1)$, which is the sequence
$$-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, \ldots$$
Taking the average of these two sequences gives
$$-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots$$
Shift this however you want to find an expression for such a sequence that only involves the basic PEMDAS operations.
For instance, this gives
$$\sin(n\pi/2) = \frac12\left((-1)^{(n+2)(n+3)/2}+(-1)^{(n+3)(n+4)/2}\right)$$
And now that you've seen it can be done, never use this unless there's absolutely no other way to solve your problem.

For completion's sake, there are exactly two expressions I've ever used to represent this sequence in a proof/model.  Depending on the context, I have only ever used $\sin(n\pi/2)$ or the imaginary part of $i^n$.  That isn't to say the above work is provably useless, but I've never used it before.

Interesting to note that this can be done, but since I was attempting to try and simplify the expression for Fourier Coefficients, I think it's safe to say that the original $\sin (n \pi / 2) $ is easier. Thank you regardless!

Within $\mathbb R$:
$$\sin\left(\frac{(2n)\pi}2\right)=0$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}2\right)=(-1)^n$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{(2n)\pi}2\right)=(-1)^n$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}2\right)=0$$
Within $\mathbb C$ (using  Euler's rule $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ and thus (for $z=\pi/2$:) $i=e^{i\pi/2}$):
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)=Im(i^n)$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)=Re(i^n)$$
--- rk
